# Связать кнопки со счетчиком PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Скажем у меня есть БД с таблицой users и поля id name count.Я сделал страницу на php ,которая выводит следующую информацию по схеме name count button
В моем случае:
Ольга 0 button
Антон 0 button
Вопрос ,как мне связать button с именем,чтобы при нажатии на кнопку изменялся count того человека напротив которого стоит кнопка.

Comment: Покажи код, который тебе не понятен.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе ставят минус за:

- отсутствие кода в вопросе: здесь не телепаты
- полное непонимание даже основ PHP, html и js: у новичков уходит всего пара часов на то, чтобы понять, как оно друг с другом связано и нагуглить документацию, примеры или куски решения
- бессмысленность задачи, которую пытаешься решить: никто так не делает
- нечеткую формулировку: тебе очевидно нужно чтобы менялся счетчик в БД, но по твоему описанию можно подумать, что просто на странице

Просто почитай это:

- http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=069
- http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php

Answer (score 0):

Чуть **потелепатил** и создал вам эту самую страницу:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user_name', 'user_pass', 'db_name');

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `count` FROM `users`");

if ($_POST['send'])
{
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `users` SET `count` = '".$_POST['count']."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'");
    header("Location: /");
}

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    ?>
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data['name']; ?>" disabled>
            <input type="text" name="count" value="<?php echo $data['count']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="send">           
        </form>
    <?php
}
```